# Why is the @ sign needed in this macro definition?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, quasiquotes

In the following `when` macro:

```
(defmacro when (condition &rest body)
  `(if ,condition (progn ,@body)))
```

Why is  there an "at" `@` sign?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When inserting computed values in quasiquoted section there are two operators:

- The "comma" operator `,`
- The "comma-splice" operator `,@`

Comma `,` inserts the value of following expression in the quasi-quoted sexpr, comma-splice instead requires the expression following is a list and can be used only inside a quasi-quoted list: the effect is inserting all elements of the expression in the quasi-quoted list in the position where the operator appears.

It's very easy to see the difference by making a little experiment

```
> (let ((x '(1 2 3 4))) `(this is an example ,x of expansion))
(THIS IS AN EXAMPLE (1 2 3 4) OF EXPANSION)

> (let ((x '(1 2 3 4))) `(this is an example ,@x of expansion))
(THIS IS AN EXAMPLE 1 2 3 4 OF EXPANSION)
```

As you can see the use of `,@` will place the elements of the list directly inside in the expansion. Without you get instead the list placed in the expansion.

Using `,@` with an expression that doesn't result in a list will be an error when the substitution is performed:

```
* (defun f (x) `(here ,@x we go))
F
* (f '(1 2 3))
(HERE 1 2 3 WE GO)
* (f '99)

debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10009F80D3}>:
  The value
    99
  is not of type
    LIST
  when binding SB-IMPL::X

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-IMPL::APPEND2 99 (WE GO)) [external]
0]
```

Using `,@` not inside a list is instead an error when the quasi-quoted section is analyzed:

```
* (defun g (x) `,@x)

debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10009F80D3}>:
  `,@X is not a well-formed backquote expression

    Stream: #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDIN* {10000279E3}>

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-IMPL::BACKQUOTE-CHARMACRO #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDIN* {10000279E3}> #<unused argument>)
0]
```

Comment: note that is NOT `@x` what causes the expansion, but `,@x`

Comment: Correct... fixed

Answer (score 2):

The `@` can also be thought of deconstructing the list and appending it to the list appears in as described in [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html).

```lisp
`(a ,@(list 1 2) c)
```

is the equivalent of:

```
(append (list 'a) (list 1 2) (list 'c))
```

which produces:

```
(a 1 2 c)
```

Answer (score 0):

That macro definition is equivalent to

```
(defmacro when (condition &rest body) 
  (list 'if condition (cons 'progn body)))
```

but without the `@` it would be equivalent to

```
(defmacro when (condition &rest body) 
  (list 'if condition (list 'progn body)))
```

Since `body` is a list, that would cause it to be evaluated as if a parenthesized  function call, e.g. `(when t 1 2 3)` would get expanded as

```
(if t (progn (1 2 3)))
```

instead of the correct

```
(if t (progn 1 2 3))
```