# Meaning of @ (at-sign) in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

You all know the story: programmer reads other people's code, programmer sees symbol they don't understand, Google fails them because it's difficult to search for non-alphanumeric symbols.

This time it's the `@` symbol, which *seems* to be used to inject the contents of one list into the middle of another. For instance:

```
`(5 6 7 ,@'(8 9) 10 11)
;=> (5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
```

I'm comfortable with this usage, but I'm wondering whether I understand the behavior of `@` correctly? Does it have other uses? And what causes the error in the following transcript (from CLISP)?

```
[1]> (list 1 2 3 4 @'(5 6 7))

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable @ has no value
```

Lastly, what exactly *is* `@`? It doesn't seem to be a function:

```
[3]> (print #'@)

*** - FUNCTION: undefined function @
```

I'm guessing it's a fundamental syntax like the backquote (`` ` ``), or comma (`,`). Is this correct?  Sorry if this is a duplicate, but once again, as far as I know it's impossible to search for `@`.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661875/why-is-the-sign-needed-in-this-macro-definition) might be useful..

Comment: @MikeChristensen That confirms my hypothesis concerning what it does, but I'd still like some additional explanations.

Comment: I found that you can actually get reasonable Google results by spelling out what the character is. For example, Google `Lisp "at sign"`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### “,@” is used to splice within backquotes…

It's described in the HyperSpec in the section on backquote:

> #### [2.4.6 Backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm)
>
> If a comma is immediately followed by an at-sign, then the form
>   following the at-sign is evaluated to produce a list of objects. These
>   objects are then “spliced” into place in the template. For example,
>   if `x` has the value `(a b c)`, then
>
> ```
>  `(x ,x ,@x foo ,(cadr x) bar ,(cdr x) baz ,@(cdr x))
> =>  (x (a b c) a b c foo b bar (b c) baz b c)
> ```

It's worth noting that `,@` isn't always necessary;  according to the same documentation:

> Anywhere “,@” may be used, the syntax “,.” may be used instead to
>   indicate that it is permissible to operate destructively on the list
>   structure produced by the form following the “,.” (in effect, to use
>   nconc instead of append).

### …but “@” on its own is just another letter…

Your intuition is mostly correct when [you ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463925/meaning-of-in-lisp#comment32393137_21464552), "so basically @ on its own means nothing and the only real operator is ,@?"  `@` can be used in other places as a normal letter.  That's why you get the error that you mentioned: `(list 1 2 3 4 @'(5 6 7))` is simply

```
(list 1 2 3 4 @ '(5 6 7))
```

and `@` is a variable, but it doesn't have a value here. Compare that with:

```
(let ((@ 4.5))
  (list 1 2 3 4 @ '(5 6 7)))
;=> (1 2 3 4 4.5 (5 6 7))
```

### …that can, unfortunately, be hard to search for.

> Sorry if this is a duplicate, but once again, as far as I know it's
>   impossible to search for "@".

Searching for documentation on certain non-alphanumeric characters can be difficult, but I've found a few techniques that can help.  E.g., if you go to lispdoc.com, you can search for `comma`, and [the results there](http://lispdoc.com/?q=comma&search=Basic%20search) will get you headed toward backquote.  (Searching for at-sign didn't help though.)  That's not a perfect solution, but it can help sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

`,@` should be considered a single entity, and the meaning of `,@` is that the following expressions is spliced into the current quasi-quoted list.

For example you cannot use

```
`,@x
```

because the quasi-quoted expression is not a list and `,@` requires a list to be spliced to.
Similarly (in my reading of the standard) you cannot use

```
`(list ,@5)
```

because `5` is not a list (however both SBCL and CLISP allow it and expand to `(list . 5)`).

## EDIT

Actually the behavior of SBCL and CLISP is acceptable, but it would also be acceptable for a compliant implementation to give an error if `,@` is used with a non-list argument.

[CLHS section 2.4.6](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) last possible expansion for `` `((,a b) ,c ,@d) `` shows that raising an error for a non-list could be acceptable too.

Comment: Nice note about the behavior of `\`,@X` where `X` isn't a list!

Answer (score 1):

Comma-at is for list splicing in CL. It places the list content into the expression containing it, removing the list's outermost parantheses.
Paul Graham's now freely available book ["On Lisp"](http://paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html) contains many more details about it, if my mind serves me right, and is a good read anyway if you want to learn more about advanced Lisp.

Comment: So basically `@` on its own means nothing and the only real operator is `,@`?